# Replace AS3 client with Twisted client

Tags: twisted

I have an existing client that is written in ActionScript that I want to completely replace.

Python and Twisted appear to be the ideal candidate.  No changes to the server are allowed.

1..What are the possible stumbling blocks?

2..Is it probable that Twisted can be used to create a bit perfect network connection that would be the same as the current client?

The connection is authenticated and uses SSL.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is too hard to answer without knowing everything about your current client.  Try something, and if you have a problem, ask a separate question.
2. Yes. Twisted doesn't have any restrictions on what kind of network traffic it can create.
3. Twisted does support SSL out of the box.